# Firefox - how do I list installed extensions and identify them in a list?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Two related questions:

1. Is there an API to produce a list of all the installed extensions in Firefox?
2. If so, how would I uniquely identify an extension? What I need is to have an ID that persists through different versions of an extension and ideally through a renaming (so name may not be the best option). Is it GUID?

Thanks!

Comment: note that you need to see `about:support` to get a complete list of extensions in firefox. If you only use `about:addons`, it will skip some (eg wikipedia, bing, amazon, etc) https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1267206

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** this answer is outdated. nsIExtensionManager was replaced by [`AddonManager`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Addons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager), and FUEL is deprecated.

You can get the list of items from nsIExtensionManager. Yes there is a unique ID for extensions (`nsIUpdateItem::id`), [as specified in the install manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/install.rdf#id).

On a second thought, this is where FUEL is really useful. Try this in the Error Console:

```
Application.extensions.all.forEach(function(item) { alert(item.id) })
```

Answer (score 2):

From outside of Firefox (in version 60.0 at least) the installed extensions list can be obtained from `extensions.json` file in profile directory. There can be also found  `extensions.sqlite` and `addons.sqlite` sqlite databases, but they don't cover all the extensions.
There is also `addons.json` but it does not contain 'active' flag (i.e. whether extension is active, enabled or disabled).

To get CSV-like list of installed extensions with type and active flag the following **XPath3** query can be used:

```
( json-doc("extensions.json") ? addons ? * )
  ! (( ?type, ?defaultLocale ?name, ?active )
    => string-join(",") || "&#xA;" ) => string-join()
```

Output example:

```
extension,Mozilla Archive Format,false
extension,Restart,false
theme,Default,false
webextension,Add HTTPS,true
webextension,Greasemonkey,true
```

NB: for a correct CSV it also needs to wrap with quotes the values containing comma or quotation mark and escape the quotation marks.

From a shell, using `xq` command, and with filter for active extensions:

```
xq ' ( json-doc("extensions.json") ? addons ? * ) [ ?active eq true() ] 
  ! (( ?type, ?defaultLocale ?name, ?active )
    => string-join(",") || "&#xA;" ) => string-join() '
```

Output example:

```
webextension,Add HTTPS,true
webextension,Greasemonkey,true
```

`xq` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare_ns_map='declare namespace map = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map";'
declare_ns_array='declare namespace array = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array";'

q="$1"; shift
saxonhe-xquery -qs:"$declare_ns_map $declare_ns_array $q" "$@" \!omit-xml-declaration=yes \!indent=yes
```

`saxonhe-xquery` script (a wrapper for Saxon XQuery):

```
#!/bin/sh
exec java -classpath /usr/share/java/Saxon-HE.jar net.sf.saxon.Query "$@"
```

#### Update

A slightly simpler query than XPath to get the same result using **[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)** JSON processor:

```
jq -j '.addons [] | ( .type, ",", .defaultLocale.name, ",", .active, "\n" )' extensions.json | sort
```

Output only active extension and generate output in CSV format (using `@csv` filter):

```
jq -r '.addons[] | select( .active == true )
  | [ .type, .defaultLocale.name, .active ] | @csv ' extensions.json
```

A similar select via the [jj](https://github.com/tidwall/jj) ([manual](https://github.com/tidwall/gjson/blob/master/SYNTAX.md)), but without an ability to have output in a plain text format (i.e. not JSON):

```
jj -i ./extensions.json 'addons.#( active == true )# 
  .[type,defaultLocale.name,active] .@pretty'
```

Comment: `jq` could be tweaked to get just "real" installed and active extensions names and sourceURI (to backup), filtering also "search.mozilla.org" ones. Also maybe @csv filter could be used.

Answer (score 1):

To get extensions list, Please take a look at `nsExtensionManager.js` in components folder, 
there is a variable called `validExtensions` which use to generate `extensions.ini` in firefox profile directory

For unique ID, I guess its depend on extensions itself, because some extensions like noscript, adblockplus use GUID, and some extensions like firebug,foxmarks using email address style.

Comment: This answer is outdated too.

Answer (score 1):

For documentation and backup purposes, I wanted a list of all the extensions I installed, including a link to its page at addons.mozilla.org so I could easily reinstall them if necessary.

First, `cd` into the firefox profile directory. For example:

```
cd ~/.mozilla/firefox/juxa1m2n.default-1644874267533
```

The addons.mozilla.org site is internationalized. When creating the URLs we need to embed our preferred language code. To prepare for this, we set a variable, `lang`, to the *language* portion of our `LANG` environment variable:

```
lang=$(grep -Eo '^[^.]*' <<<"$LANG")
```

Then use `jq` to list your enabled or disabled extensions that you installed.

### List enabled firefox extensions

```
jq --arg lang "$lang" -j '.addons |
   map(select(.type == "extension" and .location == "app-profile" and (.userDisabled | not)))
   | .[] | "- [",.defaultLocale.name,"]",
     "(https://addons.mozilla.org/\($lang)/firefox/addon/",(.id|@uri),")\n" ' \
  extensions.json
```

Result in my case:

```
- [Open in Browser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/openinbrowser%40www.spasche.net)
- [Bookmarklets context menu](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/%7B8d2a1b8a-2ff6-4bde-aae4-4a9dd54b7e66%7D)
- [ContextSearch web-ext](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/%7B5dd73bb9-e728-4d1e-990b-c77d8e03670f%7D)
- [Export Cookies](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/%7B36bdf805-c6f2-4f41-94d2-9b646342c1dc%7D)
- [Wayback Machine](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/wayback_machine%40mozilla.org)
- [Duplicate Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/%7B54fa1e34-a0ad-4526-a81b-b06139adf332%7D)
- [Reader View](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/%7B2495d258-41e7-4cd5-bc7d-ac15981f064e%7D)
- [FaviconSwitcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/%7B1220100b-db8f-419f-9cd4-ed7a51cee7f3%7D)
- [Display #Anchors](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/display-anchors%40robwu.nl)
- [CopyTabTitleUrl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/CopyTabTitleUrl%40bugbugnow.net)
- [Stylus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/%7B7a7a4a92-a2a0-41d1-9fd7-1e92480d612d%7D)
- [Nuke Anything](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/%7B1ced4832-f06e-413f-aa14-9eb63ad40ace%7D)
- [New Tab Beside](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/%7B93c2f785-16bd-49fa-91f3-6a28a8f0d7f9%7D)
- [AlwaysSmile](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/alwayssmile%40mozilla.org)
```

I formatted it as a list of links using Markdown syntax. You can paste it into a Markdown document.

### List disabled firefox extensions

```
jq --arg lang "$lang" -j '.addons | map(select(.type == "extension" and .location == "app-profile" and .userDisabled)) | .[] |
   "- [",.defaultLocale.name,"](https://addons.mozilla.org/\($lang)/firefox/addon/",(.id|@uri),")\n" ' extensions.json
```