# Howto detect a specific Firefox Add-On?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I want to detect a specific Add-On and if a user has it installed in his Browser. The Plugin is an XPI package.

I know of `navigator.plugins` but it should not be mistaken for what I want.

Comment: Why you want to uninstall something from user computer? How about uninstalling Windows?

Comment: note that you need to see `about:support` to get a complete list of extensions in firefox. If you only use `about:addons`, it will skip some (eg wikipedia, bing, amazon, etc) https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1267206

Answer (score 1):

You can find the extensions installed by [addon manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager).

Or you can just look for `nsExtensionManager.js` and use the variable called `validExtensions` which is used to create the `extensions.ini` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054364/firefox-how-do-i-list-installed-extensions-and-identify-them-in-a-list#)

Comment: Oh cool, so if the extension's ID is "bla@blu.com" how would you check for its presence from JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

I know you have checked navigator.plugins but I think this is the most accurate you can get.
What is mistaken in your case?

```
   var myPlugin = navigator.plugins['pluginName'];
   if (myPlugin === undefined) {
     // The plugin you're looking for is not present
   }
```

If it's not enough, you still can check into navigator.plugins each object, and check if the descriptions is what you're looking for

AFAIK, if you want to detect if your ads are seen by the users, you should trick with the extension (I think there is a difference between plugin and extension).
Create a script that you call "ads.js"
Into this script, create an element with a unique ID.
Into your app, check if this div has been created. If not, that means that Adblock has prevented the browser to load/run the script

Comment: AFAIK Plugins only detects stuff like Flash, Java etc == Plugins. However I want to detect Plugins, e.g. AdBlockers, Surfbars, Firebug, etc...

Comment: How come you think I want to detect AdBlock? I want to check if a certain Add-On is installed at the client's browser.